# Live-Build lb build "chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/env’: No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, chroot

I have a problem with live build

```
$ sudo lb build --interactive shell
```

returns with

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/env’: No such file or directory
```

does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same thing happen to me and I think it's because my working directory is mounted from my host OS (mac osx) via vagrant.

```
P: If the following stage fails, the most likely cause of the problem is with your mirror configuration or a caching proxy.
P: Running debootstrap...
mknod: ‘/vagrant/tutorial1/chroot/test-dev-null’: Operation not permitted
E: Cannot install into target '/vagrant/tutorial1/chroot' mounted with noexec or nodev
P: Begin unmounting filesystems...
P: Saving caches...
chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/env’: No such file or directory
```

The `'/usr/bin/env': No such file or directory` error is because debootstrap failed, and I'd bet the command being run is something along the lines of: `chroot /vagrant/tutorial1/chroot /usr/bin/env FOO=bar baz`, and chroot is failing to find `/usr/bin/env`

I moved outside of the /vagrant path on my machine and it seems to be working.

Try looking at earlier messages in the output for clues. Feel free to paste more of the output in here if you are still not certain!

Comment: This was, indeed, the source of this problem for me! Weirdly-specific, and probably the first time a “1-point” user has ever helped me in years-upon-years of Stack Exchange use  — thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@kitchen's diagnosis of what the error message means is accurate, but the scenario did not match mine. I found `./chroot/debootstrap/debootstrap.log` contains additional information about why the `debootstrap` command is dying:

```
dpkg-deb: error: archive './/var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2_arm64.deb'
has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz',
giving up
```

It turns out that the `dpkg` package was outdated. Upgrading it with `apt-get install -y dpkg` fixed [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1730627).

Answer (score 0):

If someone runs into this again (and coming from Google):

Ubuntu forgot to include some keys into ubuntu-archive-keyring that is used by Debootstrap to validate Release files.

The solution is simply run this command as root

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem sort out just install this Package

> apt install dpkg-dev

---

simple (:

Comment: Hey welcome to the site!  It would be best to explain *why* you believe this will help the OP.  Thanks!

Comment: i was just giving  a hint  to sort out the whole problem to run apt install dpkg-dev this command, you just visit it and follow this page command  your 97%problem will sortout, and remaining issue will display  when run **build lb command** then search this error on google you will get some commands command to sort out problem()100%. i know this method answering  is not so good but its 100% working

Answer (score -2):

Change your mirror, as You say lb build stop after

`chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/env’: No such file or directory`

This happened since all packages which you set in include.chroot.packages
are not all downloaded.

So system unmounted at that point, now chroot does not do anything even taking telescope:))

`change mirror in lb config , use stable mirror`

This also happened with me while building Amzux , the solution was to change the mirror.

And you are also able to manually add packages in chroot/var/apt/cache/archives